# Table text align right

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am trying to create a table in Android. 
I got really far, but I have problems with the HeadLineSum and BodySum not horizontal floating to the far right.
I made a Excel layout to show what I really wanted.

[image]

And this is what I have managed to create.
[image]

My Android Layout code:

```
    <!-- Breakfast -->
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRowHeadlineBreakfast"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewAddBreakfast"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_add" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewHeadlineBreakfast"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="80"
                    android:text="@string/breakfast"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewEnergyBreakfast"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:text="@string/energy"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayoutBreakfastItems"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRowBreakfastItems"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewBreakfastItemsName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:text="@string/name"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewBreakfastItemsEnergy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:text="@string/energy"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRowBreakfastItemsSub"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewBreakfastItemsSub"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/name" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
    <!-- //Breakfast -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Table Layout is too old technique to achieve this type of design** you should use LinearLayout for same.

If you want still achieve this type of design using **TableLayout** Just Copy Paste my code

***Here is my code***

First create **border.xml** file in to drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#fff" />

</shape>
```

then copy paste this code **main_activity.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_table_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.dhruv.demovolleyjson.TableLayout">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"

                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewHeadlineBreakfast"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Breakfast"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Energy"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Energy"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am also interested in learning how to do it in LinearLayout.